# Connect two computers on different networks using a computer that is on both networks

Tags: networking, proxy, tunnel, bridge, gateway

I have three computers on my network: `computer_1`, `computer_2`, and `computer_3`.

`Computer_3 can access computer_2`

`Computer_2 can access computer_1`

I need to access `Computer_1 from Computer_3` but `Computer_1` and `Computer_3` and one separated networks and I can't connect them using a switch or something physical.

`Computer_2` has two network interfaces.

How can I do it?

I think to use a *proxy* or a *http tunnel*, but I have no idea how to enable communication between `computer_1` and `computer_3`. Or maybe a program running on `Computer_2` that redirects `Computer_1` requests to `Computer_3` and return its responses to `Computer_1`.

I need to access a **web service** running on `Computer_3` from `Computer_1`.

All computers have *Windows 7 64 bits*.

Maybe I can do from `Computer_3` this call: http://Computer_2/WebApi, and then `Computer_2` redirects this call to http://Computer_1/WebApi.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least the following options:

- Configure computer_2 as a router and configure the other computers to use it (e.g. set up static routes)
- Create application specific relaying using something like an application-proxy or [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) or [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/)

The first option is the most general.

I'd search this site and then the intertubes for something like "configure routing on Windows 8.1" - substitute your O/S.